# Segmentation Fault after pthread_create()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

Creating a thread with this:

```
pthread_t thread; 
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*)&serve_connection, (void*)sockfd);
```

The function I am calling is defined as:

```
void serve_connection (void* sockfd) {
ssize_t  n, result;
char line[MAXLINE];
connection_t conn;
connection_init (&conn);
conn.sockfd = *((int*)sockfd);
while (! shutting_down) {
...
...
}}
```

The rest of the function is in the '...' but it is irrelevant because I have traced the seg fault to

```
conn.sockfd = *((int*)sockfd);
```

Where conn.sockfd is of type 'int'.

Originally serve_connection was:

```
void serve_connection (int sockfd){
...
conn.sockfd = sockfd;
...
}
```

But I am calling it from a thread so that had to be changed. I should also note that the sockfd being passed to pthread_create is an int with a value.

I'm also getting these warnings on compiling:

```
warning: ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 3 of âpthread_createâ between function pointer and âvoid *â
note: expected âvoid * (*)(void *)â but argument is of type âvoid *â
```

These all refer to the line where I call pthread_create. I've ignored the warnings until now because the program runs up until the line specified above so I assume the function is being called correctly. I just can't figure out what is causing the segmentation fault it as I'm still new to working with pthreads (I'm assuming I'm calling or declaring something wrong, but looking at the libraries hasn't really helped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, consider replacing

```
conn.sockfd = *((int*)sockfd);
```

by

```
conn.sockfd = (int)sockfd;
```

> You didn't have passed the *sockfd* variable as a pointer so you cannot dereference it. Take a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the assignment as follows:

```
conn.sockfd = (int)sockfd;
```